# WPF slider to a "selected textbox" (on got focus)

Tags: wpf, textbox, slider

How is the right way to bind dynamically a TextBox to a Slider?

The idea is to have many textboxes. When the user click over a TextBox, it changes his `Background Color` (showing thats it has the focus) and then if the user change the value of the Slider, the `Text` property of the `Selected Textbox` should change.

Comment: But if you click the slider the TextBox will lose focus

Comment: you are right, i mean "the last textbox selected"

Answer (score 1):

I would so this by embedding the `TextBoxes` in a `ListBox`. That way you can use list box to handle the definition of what is focused by its `SelectedItem`, and then bind the slider to the listboxes selecteditem too.

Comment: I have already created a property "SelectedTextBox" in my ViewModel. Each textbox in the UI has the event GotFocus:

Dim txt As Windows.Controls.TextBox = sender
txt.Background = Windows.Media.Brushes.LightYellow
viewmodel.SelectedTextBox = txt

This works, but how to bind the Slider to this textbox?

Answer (score 0):

As `@AlSki` mentioned you could use a `ListBox` to hold all your `TextBoxes` and bind to the `SelectedItem`

Example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider Value="{Binding SelectedItem.Text, ElementName=listbox}"/>
    <ListBox Name="listbox">
        <TextBox />
        <TextBox />
        <TextBox />
        <TextBox />
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

---

Or if the `TextBoxes` are layed out in a fashion that cant be used with an `ItemsControl` you could do this with by creating a `TextBox` `Style` and setting the Binding to the `Slider` in a Trigger

Example:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Slider Name="slider" Focusable="False"/>
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, both variants :-)